# Error.captureStackTrace no longer works with the latest version of nodejs (v0.6.11). Was it replaced?

Tags: node.js

I recently updated from nodejs v0.4.9 to v0.6.11 and noticed none of my stack traces were showing up. I depended on a few of those to for validating tests. Anyone know whats up or if theres a different way to do it?

Comment: Can you just read `err.stack` directly?

Comment: I've modeled by Error objects like this (http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) and I'm returning them in the response. I can access the stack through err.stack but it wont help when I need send a json response back with the stack.

Comment: Updated link to Express error-handling guide: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 3):

Tested today (Nov 9, 2013) with Node v0.10.5, this works:

```
var ParseError = exports.ParseError = function(message) {
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, ParseError);
  this.message = message;
}

ParseError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
ParseError.prototype.constructor = ParseError;
```

When `new ParseError('some message')` is thrown, it carries the `stack` attribute as expected when caught.